# Table cell with linebreak text runs into next line

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabu

In a tabu table, if I have long enough text in a cell, a linebreak is automatically inserted. This is fine with me and what I want. However the last line of text in that cell is basically bottom aligned with the next \hline, i.e. there is no padding.

Is this expected behavior or a bug? How can I fix it?

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
       Column 1&Column 2&Column 3&Column 4\\
    \hline
       some text&some long text some long text some long text some long text &some text&some text\\
    \hline
       some text&no problem here&some text&some text\\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For horizontal lines with improved spacing, you might consider using the `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` commands from the `booktabs` package. Please keep in mind, that these rules are incompatible with vertical lines.

Comment: I like the booktabs package. Is it compatible with fixed with tables and automatically adjusted cell width (like in the example) and automatic linebreaks?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `booktabs` package in combination with the table you showed in your question. Simply load the package, replace the `\hline` commands by the rules I listed in my previous comment and remove all vertical lines.

Comment: Can booktabs do something like `\cline{}` , i.e. horizontal lines over certain columns only?

Comment: Yes, it can. The command is `\cmidrule{1-2}` for a  line over the first and second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

somewhere before `tabu` table add `\tabulinesep=<amount>`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\tabulinesep = 3pt % <--- added
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
       Column 1&Column 2&Column 3&Column 4\\
    \hline
       some text&some long text some long text some long text some long text &some text&some text\\
    \hline
       some text&no problem here&some text&some text\\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```